# Синхронность в Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, request, асинхронность

Написал код для оповещений о новых видео на канале YouTube. Я получаю ID нового видео и сверяю его с последним ID в базе данных. Проблема в том, что из этого кода я могу получить ID видео только изнутри, при передаче в другую функцию они становятся undefined. В итоге пришел к тому, что функции работают асинхронно и не успевают получить ID друг от друга. Как сделать синхронность?

```
        setInterval(function() {
          var videos = getLatestVideo();
          console.log("Video in interval "+videos);
          ifNewVideo(videos);
        }, 60000); //Каждую минуту проверяю наличие новых видео


        function getLatestVideo() { // Получаю ID последнего видео на канале YouTube
        var response;
        request.get('https://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) console.log(error);
           response = JSON.parse(body).items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
           console.log("Response 1: "+response)
          });
          console.log("Response 2: "+response)
        return response;
        } 

        function ifNewVideo(videoId) { //Сверяю его с последним видео в бд

        var latestVideo;
        Video.find(function (err, latest) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
          latestVideo = latest[0].id;
          console.log("latestVideo 1: "+latestVideo)
        });
          console.log("latestVideo 2: "+latestVideo)

        console.log("URL = "+videoId +". DB = "+latestVideo);

        if (videoId!==latestVideo) {
    console.log("This video is new!");
    }
}
```

[image: логи]

Comment: Никак, это JavaScript. Есть callbacks, promises, generators, async/await.

Comment: Засунь одну в другую

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач, я обычно использую библиотеку Async.js ссылка на документацию
https://caolan.github.io/async/ раздел Control Flow -> series (как вариант)